# Tensorflow Lite .tflite model not working iOS but works on android

Tags: ios, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

The working .tflite model in android is not working on iOS app

Its giving NULL for **out**

`uint8_t* out = interpreter->typed_tensor<uint8_t>(input);`

May I know what are all the possibilities that **out = NULL**

And may I know whats **input** cause for the example provided on tensorflow-lite the **input = 88** and I'm getting **input = 27**

`int input = interpreter->inputs()[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, i.e. used float instead of uint8_t

```
float* out = interpreter->typed_tensor<float>(input);
```

But still waiting for answer of this question

> May I know whats input cause for the example provided on
>   tensorflow-lite the input = 88 and I'm getting input = 27
>
> int input = interpreter->inputs()[0];